Trouble pasting the same variable into multiple AHK scripts
I have recently started using AHK to bill procedure medications for a proprietary program at work. We have 8 doctors that rotate through here and so I have 8 different versions of this script that I use depending on who is here that day.
Instead of changing the lot number and expiration date 8 times whenever I open a new case of meds, I would like to have 1 master list that this script can pull the number from.
I have made an LibreOffice Calc sheet (no Excel at work) with all the numbers/dates but haven't been able to find a way to make AHK copy and paste from it, ideally without having to actually open the spreadsheet. We have a bunch of different meds but here is the script for one of them.
!B::
SEND, J0702
SEND, {TAB 4}
SEND, 2
SEND, {ENTER}
CoordMode, Mouse, Window
MouseClick, left, 940, 1042
SEND, {TAB}
SEND, b
SEND, {DOWN 3} 
SEND, {RETURN} 
SEND, {TAB 3} 
SEND, 1 
SEND, {TAB 2} 
SEND, 16853636 (lot #) 
SEND, {TAB} 
SEND, 05/27 (exp date) 
SEND, {TAB 8} 
SEND, scott 
SEND, {RETURN} 
SEND, {TAB} 
SEND, {RETURN} 
RETURN


here is a discussion ... https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=16046 ... the LibreCalc sheet is manipulated directly,  not through simulated keystrokes

LibreOffice has a database program ... it may be more convenient than a spreadsheet

this may help with your research ... https://duckduckgo.com/?q=ahk+libreoffice&ia=web

how many different variable sets there are? if not so many and are not changing often, you could just write down inside AHK variables and show them in simple pop-up window prompting to select one, then running paste script.

You could always run some PowerShell to help with that task. Hard to give you examples without knowing how your CSV/sheet looks, but here are some helpful references:

Import-Csv - gives you an array of objects with your data
Where-Object (abbreviated ?) - lets you filter the list and find the proper record
Select-Object (Select shorthand) - to then select the specific field(s) you want to copy

You can chain all of these with pipes (|) and get a single field result in standard output. Lastly use AHK's preferred method of getting said output:
shell := ComObjCreate('WScript.Shell')
exec := shell.Exec('pwsh -NoLogo -Command "Import-Csv ... | Select SomeField"')
; Copy stdout to predefined global clipboard var
clipboard := exec.StdOut.ReadAll()

Pasting into CSV can be scripted similarly, with help of Export-Csv and typical PowerShell object manipulation.
